# jquery validate plugin add custom option if form has class

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

How would I set the validate plugin to work different (add the option ignore) on forms which have a class of `validate-hidden`

```
var theForms = $("form[method=post]:not(.noValidate)");
if (theForms.length){
    theForms.each(function(){
        var $dis = $(this); 
        validater = $dis.validate();        
        if($dis.hasClass("validate-hidden")){
            $dis.validate({ ignore: '' });
        }
    }); 
}
```

I have tired this but it doesnt have the ignore option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this issue but using the setDefaults method and order.

```
var theForms = $("form[method=post]:not(.noValidate)");
if (theForms.length){
    theForms.each(function(){
        var $dis = $(this); 
        if($dis.hasClass("validate-hidden")){
            jQuery.validator.setDefaults({ 
            ignore: ''
            });
        }
        validater = $dis.validate();        
    }); 
}
```